# How to find a value in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a method for me to retrieve the value 4500?
I know i can use collection.max or collection.min for highest and lowest but how do i get the value in between? thanks

```
int value = 4000;

for(int i = 0; i < Array.size();i++){
        Array.get(i);

    if (value < Array.get(i) && value <= Array.get(i))
    {
        value=????;


    }

Array.add(1000);
Array.add(2000);
Array.add(3000);
Array.add(4500);    
Array.add(5000);
Array.add(8000);
```

Comment: which programming language is this? JAVA?

Comment: when you post a question next time, please make sure to tell as much details as possible and clearly specify which programming language it is and add tags appropriately. this will make sure that right people see your question and answer it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is sorted do a `BinarySearch` otherwise do a `LinearSearch`

e.g.

```
Collections.binarySearch(array,value);
```

Linear search:

```
int size = array.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
   if(array.get(i) >= value){       
      if ( i + 1 < size){
         return array.get(i+1);  
      }
      else {
         // No element found                    
      }
}
```

Comment: i would want to search for the number larger than 4000 and smaller or equal to a number in the list